# Sort JS object by decrementing value (with unknown key)

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to sort a simple object with unknown keys by highest integer value. Is there neat code to do this?

I've tried this, but with no success.

```js
let fixSort = {};
  Object.keys(leaderboard).sort().forEach(function(key){
  fixSort[key] = leaderboard[key];
});
console.log(fixSort);
```

Here is the object:

```js
let leaderboard = {
  "Bob" : 2,
  "Jimmy" : 1,
  "Emma" : 6
}
```

My goal is to have it sorted as:

```js
{
  "Emma" : 6,
  "Bob" : 2,
  "Jimmy" : 1
}
```

Comment: No you can't sort in this manner (based on values), You need to use array in such cases

Comment: Object keys that aren't numeric are sorted by order of entry. So you *could* pull out the entires, sort them, and make a new object. Probably better to use an array if order matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well "you could":

```
 const fixSort = {};

 for(const [k, v] of Object.entries(leaderboard).sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]))
  fixSort[k] = v;
 }
```

But thats honestly a bad way to structure this (as adding new key-value pairs is impossible as you have to recreate the whole thing). Instead use an array of objects:

```
  const leaderboard = [
   { name: "Jack", score: 7 },
   //...
 ];
```

If you need a lookuptable, then just create one based on that object:

```
 const byName = {};
 for(const player of leaderboard)
   byName[player.name] = player;
```

For sure you can also sort the array:

```
 leaderboard.sort((a, b) => a.score - b.score);
```

Then you can easily add / remove players.

```
 function addToLeaderBoard(player) {
   leaderboard.push(player);
   leaderboard.sort((a, b) => a.score - b.score);
   byName[player.name] = player;
 }
```

Comment: It's important to note that names must be unique otherwise the `byName` table may not match `leaderboard`

Comment: @yoav sure but the OP would face that provlem with his version too so ...

Comment: In his version there's only one table, so there can be no discrepancies right? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Another option - use `Object.entries` to create an array from the `leaderboard`, sort it by value, then rebuild individual objects into an array, to maintain the sorted order.

```js
const leaderboard = {
  "Bob" : 2,
  "Jimmy" : 1,
  "Emma" : 6
}

console.log(Object.entries(leaderboard).sort((a,b) => b[1] - a[1]).map(person => ({[person[0]]: person[1]})))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) can take a custom compare function. That's what you want.

```
// Gives you an array
const keyArray = Object.keys(leaderboard)
const fixedSort = keyArray.sort((a, b) => {
  if (leaderboard[a] > leaderboard[b]) {
    return 1
  }
  return -1
})
console.log(fixedSort);
```

Comment: Jonas' answer above contains a much better version of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
let leaderboard = {
  "Bob" : 2,
  "Jimmy" : 1,
  "Emma" : 6
}

var newObj={};

Object.keys(leaderboard).sort((a,b)=>leaderboard[b]-leaderboard[a]).forEach((i, v)=> newObj[i]=leaderboard[i]);
```

[image]

For change Object to sorted array, Because If you try to expand the obj in console it will show, you again unsorted, but in real it is sorted, For completely clear, our doubt, we can change this object to array
use below code

```
var result = Object.keys(newObj).map(function(key) {
  return [key, newObj[key]];
});
console.log(result);
```

it will look like below image
[image]